# Redirecting errors to a file in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I know you have to use ...

```
php lots_of_errors.php > temp.txt 2>&1
```

...if you want to redirect the error logs into a temp.txt

- 1 = standard output (where programs print normal output)
- 2 = standard error (where programs print errors)

You use `&1` to indicate that it's a file descriptor and not a file but why don't you use & sign in front of 2 like `&2>&1` then?

Comment: The proper way to redirect just the errors is `2>errorfile` though. `>temp.txt` is really a shorthand for `1>temp.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `&` symbol is how the shell knows you are redirecting to a file descriptor instead of a file.  That is, the lefthand-side (LHS) of the `>` operator is *always* a file descriptor, but the RHS is generally a filename.  So this:

```
2>1
```

Would redirect file descriptor 2 to a filenamed "1".  The amperand is how the shell knows you mean "file descriptor 1":

```
2>&1
```

Comment: why wouldn't &2 would in &2>&1 work though? Letting it be known that it's a file descriptor as well